# Resolve scoped services based on current tenant from Blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, middleware, multi-tenant

I have an existing ASP.NET Core 6 MVC application which I try to build upon with Blazor (server) components. The application contains a multi-tenancy structure, where tenants can be created, edited and switched at runtime.

There are some services that are scoped to use the current tenant, for example our database accessing logic (using NPoco, **not** Entity Framework). The connection to the database is made based on the current tenant.

The tenant currently is determined by using the 'tenantId' route parameter, for example:

```cs
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/{tenantId}/example"]
```

Using an `IMiddleware` implementation, this 'tenantId' route param is retrieved from the url and set on a scoped service:

```cs
var tenantId = context.Request.RouteValues["tenantId"];
context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ITenantContext>().Current = tenantId;
```

This all works well using standard MVC, Web API, Razor etc.

Now I introduced Blazor components, I need to invoke some services that invoke database interaction, and therefore need the current tenant to be resolved:

Component:

```
[Inject]
private IExampleService ExampleService { get; set; }
```

Example Service:

```cs
public class ExampleService : IExampleService
{
    private readonly ITenantContext _tenantContext;
    public ExampleService(ITenantContext tenantContext) => _tenantContext = tenantContext;

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        // How to make sure that `ITenantContext.Current` has the correct value here
        var db = new Database(new SqliteConnection($"data source={_tenantContext.Current}.db3"));
        await db.Query("SELECT 1 FROM Example");
    }
}
```

However, using Blazor, the 'scoped service' that is used in the middleware, is not the same as that of a Blazor circuit.

I also tried using an `AsyncLocal` instead of a scoped service, but it seems that the Blazor component runs on a different `SynchronizationContext` than the one that is invoked through the middleware.

This all makes sense, but I cannot make sense of how it then should be implemented in Blazor.

**Question**

How can I set the current `tenantId` correctly in a Blazor scope?

Note that everything must remain 'Blazor-agnostic', so everything will still work in the plain MVC/Razor implementations.